# Twig include with rerender

Tags: twig

I want to include some template and append on button click (by js), and I need each included template to have a unique id.

Here is the logic where I appending the templates:

```
<button type="submit" id="addTranslationFields">Add translations</button>
// and js
$('#addTranslationFields').on('click', function (event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   event.stopPropagation();

   let part = `{% include 'translationPart.twig' with {'languages': languages,}%}`;
   $('.table tbody').append(part);
});
```

Here is the how I  generate uuid in the `translationPart.twig`

```
    {% set uuid = uuid() %}
    {{ uuid }}
```

The issue is that UUID is the same for all of the created templates. I understand why it's happening, it's b-z twig generated server-side and at the moment of generation it sees only one include. But is there some option to rerender included template for each new included copy? Or maybe some other way to set different UUIDs for each of the included templates.

**Updated**

`uuid()` is a custom twig function

```
$twig->addFunction(
    new TwigFunction(
        'uuid',
        static function(): string {
             return Uuid::uuid4()->toString();
        }
    )
);
```

Comment: let's start with how this code works in your template --- `{% set uuid = uuid() %}` that is not part of twig.

Comment: uuid() is a custom twig function which using ` ramsey/uuid` to generate new UUID

Comment: You could get content of template via ajax request. Create route which renders translationPart.twig. Or you can use some string instead of uuid and replace that string: let part = '... string ...".replace with js generated uuid

Comment: I know I can use ajax, but I do not want it for such a simple thing. There can be even 50 translations, and it's mean 50 ajax calls. Can you please explain what you mean by "you can use some string instead of uuid and replace that string: let part = '... string ...".replace" ?

Comment: If uuid needs to be generated by server, this wont work. But you could {% set uuid = '#_SOME_STRING_TO_REPLACE_#' %}. After that you can generate uuid inside your javascript function and let part = `{% include 'translationPart.twig' with {'languages': languages,}%}`.replace('#_SOME_STRING_TO_REPLACE_#', generatedUuidVar);

Comment: it can work, let me try

Comment: it's working you can create an answer, and I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this via **ajax calls**, or **string replacement**.

**String replacement**

Twig template (translationPart.twig)

```
{% set uuid = '#_SOME_STRING_TO_REPLACE_#' %} 
{{ uuid }}
```

Javascript

```
<button type="submit" id="addTranslationFields">Add translations</button>
// and js
$('#addTranslationFields').on('click', function (event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   event.stopPropagation();

   let generatedUuid = generateUuidByJavascript();

   let part = `{% include 'translationPart.twig' with {'languages': languages,}%}`.replace('#_SOME_STRING_TO_REPLACE_#', generatedUuid);
   $('.table tbody').append(part);
});
```

[Uuidjs](https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid) can be used for generating uuid.